# inside div automatic fit width of li in ie

Tags: html, css, dhtml, css-float

```
<div style='width:500px'>  
<ul>  
  <li> some text in 1 line</li>  
  <li> some text in 1 line</li>  
  <li> some text 2 line</li>  
  <li> some 2</li>  
  <li> 2</li>  
</ul>
</div>
```

I don't know what is the correct css code for display of items in ie like:

first two results automatic fit in first line and rest of the results on second line.
 **so basic idea is to let the li get it's own width depending on the data size.**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two ways to achieve what I think you're asking:

Option 1:
Make the `<li>` tags `display:block;`, and `float:left;`

Option 2:
Make the `<li>` tags `display:inline-block;` and `white-space:nowrap;`

I'd go for option 2 myself, as it'll avoid the quirks you can get with floats. Also you may find you end up needing nowrap anyway, even with option 1.

[EDIT]

You may also need to style the `<ul>` tag. Maybe `width:100%;` and/or `display:block;`.

I still say `display:inline-block;` and `white-space:nowrap;` should do it for the `<li>` tags. But if it isn't working, it would help if you said in what way it's not working.

Also: You've also been saying some answers aren't working in IE, but you haven't said which version of IE -- IE6,7,8 and 9 have *very* different levels of support for CSS; it would help to know which ones you need to support.

Comment: display:block is useless when using float rule.

Comment: @Mat: All floated items should be blocks. (using float may force this anyway, but I'd always prefer to be explicit)

Comment: not "should be" but "are" : http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 1):

You've got several ways to do what you want:

- As MatTheCat says, `display: inline` with one `display: block` will work
- Similarly, `float: left;` on all but the second will also do the trick
- Set them all to `display: inline` and have a `<br />` at the end of the second element (a bit nasty, but simple)

However, you're probably far better off treating them as two separate lists. Without knowing what you're using it for, it's hard to say, but splitting the elements up will make it more readable and let you have better control over the positioning and styling of the two lines.

If the aim is just to have the list elements flow horizontally to fill the div and "first two on first line" is just an example, then simply set `display: inline` on each list element.

If you specifically want the first two results to have a width of 250px (half of your div), set the style as `float: left; width: 50%;` on those two and have the remainder diaplay inline.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest styling the navigation "like" a table :

- Containter div - display: table; equilivent to `<table>`
- List containter - display: table-row; equilivent to `<tr>`
- List Items - display table: table-cell; equilivent to `<td>`

Padding on the `<a>` element style is just to even the spacing and can be adjusted as needed, the cell items work out the remaining width and use it up relative on the cell sizes.

Working on FF / Chrome / Safair /IE 9 & 8

IE7 and below you will need to use a floating solution!

Working example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        div {
            margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
            width: 954px;
            height: 36px;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
            display: table;
        }

        ul {
            width: 100%;
            display: table-row;
            list-style: none;
            height: 100%;
        }


        li {
            display: table-cell;
            white-space: nowrap;
            border: 1px solid #00ff00;
            color: #ff0000;
        }

        a {
            text-align: center;
            display: block;
            padding: 0 15px;
            line-height: 36px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Item1</a></li>
            <li><a>Long Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a>Very Long Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a>Even longer example Item 4</a></li>
            <li><a>Item5</a></li>
            <li><a>Item6</a></li>
            <li><a>Medium Item7</a></li>
            <li><a>Item8</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `display: table` doesn't work in older browsers, so this solution is only helpful in a few scenarios. Though you do get +1 for keeping a semantic HTML structure.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I just tested in IE using F12 and changing back the compatibility, IE7 and backwards don't support the display: table*; css options.

Answer (score 0):

Float the div, it should help...

Comment: problem is not with the div, it's with the li.  li must  get it's own width depending on the data size.

Comment: What is it doing then right now? It's really hard to understand what you actually trying to achieve... try to make it more clear.

Comment: Li is suppose to display items on same line , which is happening in firefox by using float:left but not in ie. the problem is that LI must take width automatic according to it's content otherwise shift to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to apply

```
li { display:inline; }
```

and insert a `<li>` without this rule to perform a line break.

But can't you place all data in the same line in ONE `<li>` ?

Comment: Thanks MaTheCat, but there are events triggered on click of the li, so results are show according to that.

Answer (score 0):

May be floating properties may help

`<div style='width:500px; overflow: hidden;'>

<ul>

<li> some text in 1 line</li>

<li> some text in 1 line</li>

<li> some text 2 line</li>

<li> some 2</li>

<li>2</li>

</ul>

</div>`

`li {

   float: left;

   display: block;
}`